# How to selectively show portions of an iframe website using HTML

Tags: html

How to selectively show portions of an iframe website using HTML? The current website shows the entire iframe website and needs scrolling when I choose the options on the table as shown.

[image]

But I want to show a particular portion of an iframe website without showing the other articles in the iframe website when I press on the option on the main website as shown below.

[image]

How do we pull this off? Thanks!

The code I used for the iframe website is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    body {
  background-image: url('20211121_175201.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

p,h1 {color:white;}
</style>
<head>
<title>Wacky Ideas List of Ideas</title>
</head>
<body>


<table style="float: right;margin-right: 160px;display: none">
    <tr>
        <th>Wacky Ideas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#A1">Model Cardboard Jet Engine</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#A2">Toy Electric Fan</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#A3">Toy Model Car</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>


<h1 id="A1">Model Cardboard Jet Engine</h1>

<p style = "width: 100%;text-align: left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet quam non erat luctus vehicula a id augue.....</p>
</p>

<hr>

<h1 id="A2">Toy Electric Fan</h1>

<p style = "width: 100%;text-align: left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet quam non erat luctus vehicula a id augue....</p>

<hr>

<h1 id="A3">Toy Model Car</h1>

<p style = "width: 100%;text-align: left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet quam non erat luctus vehicula a id augue.... </p>

</body>
</html>
```

The code I used for the main website is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

    table,th,td{border: 1px solid white;color: white;height: 50px;font-size: 20px}
    body {
  background-image: url('20211121_175201.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

p,h1 {color:white;}
</style>
<head>
<title>Wacky Ideas</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="color: white;height: 50px">Wacky Ideas</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>


<table style="float: right;margin-right: 160px">
    <tr>
        <th>Wacky Ideas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="file:///C:/Users/pc/Desktop/experimental%20website/wacky%20ideas%20list%20of%20ideas.html#A1" target="iframe_a">Model Cardboard Jet Engine</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="file:///C:/Users/pc/Desktop/experimental%20website/wacky%20ideas%20list%20of%20ideas.html#A2" target="iframe_a">Toy Electric Fan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="file:///C:/Users/pc/Desktop/experimental%20website/wacky%20ideas%20list%20of%20ideas.html#A3" target="iframe_a">Toy Model Car</td>
    </tr>

</table>

<iframe src="file:///C:/Users/pc/Desktop/experimental%20website/wacky%20ideas%20list%20of%20ideas.html" name="iframe_a" height="1000px" width="1100px"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you all!

Comment: By not using iframes, they are not made for this.

Comment: @cloned Hello, comrade! It seems so. I couldn't pull it off using iframes. An alternative would be making individual articles on individual webpages and just make it appear on the main website via iframe. It gets the job done. But I wonder what other HTML magic we can get hands on that produces the same effect as described in the post.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's impossible to do it. An alternative is to making individual articles on individual webpages and just make it appear on the main website via iframe. It gets the job done.

Thank you!